# Retrieving uuid from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I assign `uuid()` to the `id` field. It works perfectly. But I don't know how to `echo` the generated `uuid` back to the user. How can I do this?

My code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (id,firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES (UUID(),:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

    // insert a row
    $firstname = "John";
    $lastname = "Doe";
    $email = "john@example.com";
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Having `UUID` as primary key is a bad choice. It's great when you have distributed database, but having non-integer key will only create problems for you because of how MySQL and InnoDB operate. A much wiser choice would be to have two fields - `id` as auto_increment and `uu_id` (or something) which can be `UUID()`. Then it becomes trivial to retrieve the `UUID()` - simply select using `lastInsertId()` which gives you the value of last `auto_increment`.

Comment: Ok let's say I do this. I add another column `uu_id` and I give it a value  `UUID()`.And leave the `id` as `auto increment`.

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (uu_id,firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES (UUID(),:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':uu_id', $uuid);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);`

But when I call `lastInsertId()` it will only give the auto incremented id not the uu_id,right?

Comment: Then what your code needs after `$stmt->execute()` is `$uuid = $conn->query("SELECT uu_id FROM MyGuests WHERE id = " . $conn->lastInsertId())->fetchColumn();`. You can do the snippet with prepared statement if you want to, I chose `query` for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your only choice is separating this into two queries.

- `SELECT UUID()`
- Retrieve created UUID into a php variable (`$uuid`)
- Insert that variable into your prepared statement.

  ```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (id,firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES (:uuid,:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':uuid', $uuid);
  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
  ```

Comment: Could you be more specific please.
I made the changes you wrote in the code but still not working.
How to SELECT UUID() ?  I know I am a noob...

Comment: Sorry, you cannot expect people here to write the entire code for you. My answer was clear enough as it is.